# Need to make an element outside the parent which have overflow-y auto

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following code, I need to make the close icon positioned outside the div. I can't use `overflow: hidden;`. Is there anyway to get this sorted without using `overflow: hidden;` or `position: fixed` for the close div.

JSFiddle of below code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mannyuiux/jhwu9n4r/4/.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div tabindex="-1" class="dialog__content dialog__content__active" style="z-index: 202;">
  <div class="dialog dialog--active" style="width: 1000px;">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="close">
        <img src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_211963.png" alt="Close" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
/* CSS */
.dialog__content {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 6;
    outline: none;
  }


  .dialog {
    box-shadow: 0px 11px 15px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 24px 38px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 9px 46px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 24px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: inherit;
  }
  .dialog:not(.dialog--fullscreen) {
    max-height: 90%;
  }
  .card {
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 70px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    display: block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    min-width: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  }
  .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: 0;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
  }
  .close img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to remove "overflow-y: auto;" from ".dialog".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `overflow-y: auto;` on dialog element is the issue. It will behave the same as overflow-hidden in this case, making the child element close icon invisible if it's placed outside.

If you can't remove the `overflow-y: auto;` then you should wrap the dialog in another div (that has no overflow value set but has `position: relative` set) and then also make the close icon a direct child of that element.

Like this:

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <div class="dialog dialog--active" style="width: 1000px;">
    <div class="card" />
  </div>
  <div class="close">
    <img src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_211963.png" alt="Close" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not implemented fully but it gave me an idea to solve this one. Time saved :)

Answer (score 1):

remove `overflow-y:auto` from`.dialog` class